# Using reflection in C# to modify fields in a loop, extension method

Tags: c#, reflection, types, extension-methods, field

After retrieving data from a database I find myself doing this to create a domain object from the data in a `DataRow` (in this case, a DVD):

```
DataRow drDvd = myDataTable.Rows[0];
Dvd myDvd = new Dvd();
myDvd.id = drDvd.Field<long>("id");
myDvd.title = drDvd.Field<string>("title");
myDvd.description = drDvd.Field<string>("description");
myDvd.releaseDate = drDvd.Field<DateTime>("releaseDate");
```

As I soon felt of course, I am doing this over and over in pseudo-code:

```
myDvd.field = drDvd.Field<field.type>(field.name);
```

And I wondered if I could get it into a loop, however I've never used reflection before. The code I tried is this:

```
Dvd aDvd = new Dvd();
Type t = aDvd.GetType();
FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();
foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
{
    fi.SetValue(aDvd, drDvd.Field<fi.FieldType>(fi.Name));
}
```

The problem is, as you may know, that the extension for the `Field` method of class `DataRow` does not accept a variable and needs to be explicitely filled in.

I am not that experienced in C# so I would like to pose the following two questions:

1. **Is it good practice what I am trying to do?**
2. **How can I fill in the correct extension** for `Field<extension>(name)`?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of Reflection, please consider using fast-member: http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember be sure to go through its unit test to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the method info for the generic method, and call invoke on it. This way you can pass in the generic type to it programmatically. I'm on my phone, but it should look something like this:

```
MethodInfo mField = typeof(Dvd).GetMethod("Field");
MethodInfo genericMethod = mField.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { fi.FieldType });

GenericMethod.Invoke(aDvd,new Object[]{fi.Name});
```

Comment: Ok I updated my answer--you should be able to get it from the code I have. Good luck!

Comment: Glad to hear, I've also updates the invoke call to have the proper method signature

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a bad practice to use reflection when it is not really necessary. Because reflection methods are checked at runtime rather than compile time, faulty code is harder to track, because the compiler can't check for errors.

If I were you, id have a look at the Entity Framework, because youre basically mapping database data to domain objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the remark. The problem is that I am a student, and they haven't taught this in school. I'm currently working on something big, of which the deadline is pretty near, so I can't take the time right now to read that entire page. I will do so later, though.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called Object-Relational Mapping or ORM. There are a lot of good frameworks out there for doing this including Entity Framework although LINQ-to-SQL is probably better if you haven't used one before. Both you can add as items in Visual Studio an there's a designer for getting them set up. Both also allow you to directly execute a SQL query so you can just use the object mapping part they provide to solve you problem in a more performant and well tested way. Certainly a better use of time than trying to get reflection right.

Comment: I guess they didn't teach you reflection, because it is pretty advanced stuff. You said you are a student. If I were to judge your project, I would be excited if my student had found out about reflection all by himself, though the way you use it here, tells me you don't really understand what reflection is. For this kind of stuff, you should use an ORM like the Entity Framework. You should only use reflection when it is strictly necessary. For example, the .NET reflector, which shows you the C#/MSIL code of a compiled program. But hey, that's just my opinion ;-).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way of constructing and populating your domain object

```
    DataRow drDvd = new DataRow();
    Dvd aDvd = new Dvd();
    Type type = typeof(Dvd);
    foreach (FieldInfo fi in type.GetFields())
    {
        fi.SetValue(aDvd, drDvd[fi.Name]);
    }
```

Your approach of using DataRow.Field may be round about. In you case, it is not applicable.

Alternatively you can think about using one of the Entity frameworks (NHibernate, Microsoft EF etc) in your application.

Comment: That way, you would be setting all my field values to an `Object`. The `Field` method allows for strong typing. I want a `long` to be in a `long` field...

Answer (score 0):

I would do a custom attribute.  In doing an attribute you are stuck with your field name being the same as the database.  I currently use this in my current applications and it works great.  It is very similar to Entity SQL.

```
public class SqlMetaAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have your class like this

```
public class Person
{
    [SqlMeta(ColumnName = "First_Name")]
    publice string FirstName { get; set; }

    [SqlMeta(ColumnName = "Last_Name")]
    publice string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

You would then have a helper class with the same kind of functions.  In this case I am assuming the outside caller is looping through the datatable.  Making it generic using the template T makes this really reusable.  Rather than just having a "DVD" type implementation and coping and pasting for another.

```
public static T CreateObjectFromRow<T>(DataRow row)
{
    var newObject = new T();

    if (row != null) SetAllProperties(row, newObject);

    return newObject;
}

public static void SetAllProperties<T>(DataRow row, T newObject)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach(var propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        SetPropertyValue(row, newObject, propertyInfo);
    }
}
public static void SetPropertyValue(DataRow row, T newObject, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var columnAttribute = propertyInfo.FindAttribute<SqlMetaAttribute>();

    if (columnAttribute == null) return;

    // If the row type is different than the object type and exception will be thrown, but that is
    // okay because if that happens you have to fix your object you are using, or might need some
    // more custom code to help you with that.
    propertyInfo.SetValue(newObject, row.GetValue<object>(columnAttribute.ColumnName), null);
}

// Extension method for row.GetValue<object> used above
public static T GetValue<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    if (row.ColumnNameNotFound(columnName) || row.Table.Columns[columnName] == null || row[columnName] is DBNull)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    return (T)row[columnName];
}
```

Comment: That looks really great... But how about fields that are not a string? Will it find `long` and `bool` values correctly? The datatype used in our database is `bit` for booleans...

Comment: You'd basically be re-implementing Entity Framework Code First by doing this. Here is the "SqlMeta" attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.columnattribute(v=vs.103).aspx